# $a^n$ invertible then $a$ invertible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let A be a ring. Let $a\in A$. If there exists an $n\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $a^n$ is invertible, then $a$ is invertible.

If $a^n$ is invertible, then there exists $b\in A$ such that $a^n \cdot b = b \cdot a^n = 1_{A}$. From this I can see that $a$ has a right and a left inverse, $b \cdot a^{n-1}$ and $ a^{n-1} \cdot b$, respectively. If these two are equal, then it's proven. If I'm not mistaken, I can't simply multiply both by $a$ in both sides, because I don't know yet that a is in fact invertible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $g\in A$ has a left inverse $c\in A$ and a right inverse $d\in A$. Then, 
$$
c=c 1_{A}=c(gd)=(cg)d=1_{A}d=d.
$$

In particular, in your case, taking $g=a$, $c=ba^{n-1}$, and $d=a^{n-1}b$, you can conclude that $a^{n-1}b=ba^{n-1}$, and hence, that $a$ is invertible.